# BB 10 cascade Listview textstyle color randomly updated after scrolling

Tags: blackberry-10

In my BB10 app i have `Listview` with `textstyle` having Green color and Red color to random text. But when i scroll the list view the color shifts and set to wrong texts example:

```
Apple ==> Red
Bananna == > green
after scrolling 
Apple ==> Green
bananna ==> Red
```

this is a long list so it happens to the items which will be visible after scrolling

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this happens because it reuses elements to save on memory. I'm not sure though

Comment: Is there any solution so that i can optimise and fix this

Comment: I wouldn't know. Ask on BlackBerry support forums, they could have an answer

Comment: Hi Bojan,
I have got the solution its the below code

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution its the below code

```
Label {
      id: alertTypeLable 
      text: qsTr(ListItemData.alertType) + Retranslate.onLanguageChanged
      horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Left
      verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
      textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XSmall
      textStyle.color: {
          if (ListItemData.success.toString() == "true") {
              return Color.Green
          }
          else {
              return Color.Red
          }
      }
}
```